# Find the degree of a ODE $(y''')^{\frac{4}{3}}+(y')^{\frac{1}{5}}+ y = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the degree of the differential equation.

$$(y''')^{\frac{4}{3}}+(y')^{\frac{1}{5}}+ y = 0$$

The answer is available (order $= 3$; degree $= 60$). I need help with the steps. I'm stuck in eliminating the radicals of the differential coefficients.

Comment: Use LaTeX please.

Comment: Thank you! This was my first time.

Comment: The degree of a differential equation is the degree of the highest derivative which occurs in it, after the differential equation has been made free from radicals and fractions as far as the derivatives are concerned.

Comment: The degree is meaningless if the equation is not a polynomial. And even then, the only useful degree is that of the leading derivative, as that tells you how many solution curves can originate (maximally) in each initial point.

Comment: I've tried different pairings and taken powers of 3 and 5 on each side. Nothing has worked. Perhaps I'm missing something subtle here. Any help is welcome.

Comment: The later question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3619469/find-the-degree-of-the-differential-equation-left-fracd3ydx3-right/3619508#3619508 already has an answer. @gemspark : Does this give you an idea to argue if the degree should be 60 or 20?

Comment: Sorry @LutzLehmann the answer is opaque to me. I do understand that each of the term  are different and can be subbed as $a,b,c$. 
But how does x and product of products and the series range $q:q^5=1$ come into the picture? Could you explain? Is this some method?

Comment: You can remove algebraic terms by constructing an expression that is symmetric in all the possible variants of that term. In a complex sense, $a^{4/3}$ has 3 variants that differ by a unit cube root, and $b^{1/5}$ has 5 such variants differing by a 5th unit root. As the expression should still have the original solutions, you take the product of all the conjugate expressions. The result is completely polynomial by the theory of symmetric polynomials.

Comment: One could also write this using 2 resultants. In that product you get $(a^{4/3})^{15}=a^{20}$ as the highest power of any term with $a$. I do no longer remember why I confirmed the given solution of 60.

Comment: When you say, we can "remove" algebraic terms, do you mean replace algebraic term with any other algebraic term? Also how do we get the other conjugate expressions for the product? 
I could understand your point about conjugates but how do I get them in the expression.

Comment: Since I am unaware about the theory of symmetric polynomials, could you direct me to some source of your reasoning or a more elaborate the reasoning of your proof in even simpler words and carrying on from there? 
At this point I feel it would be more easier for me to understand with an example given the difficulty I am facing in fathoming from theoretical comments.

Comment: @gemspark : Symmetric polynomials are the generalization of the Viete rules for the roots of polynomials. Every expression that is completely symmetric in the roots, that is, under all permutations in the root set, can also be expressed just in the coefficients of the polynomial, not involving any roots at all. As said, the simplest form it the Viete rules comparing the coefficients in $a_nx^n+...+a_1x+a_0=a_n(x-\xi_1)...(x-\xi_n)$, where the right side is symmetric in the roots and the left side only contains the polynomial coefficients.

Answer (score 2):

Went through @Lutz's answer [Find the degree of the differential equation $\left( \frac{d^3y}{dx^3} \right)^{\frac{4}{3}} + \left( \frac{dy}{dx} \right)^{\frac{1}{5}} + y = 0.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3619469/find-the-degree-of-the-differential-equation-left-fracd3ydx3-right/3619508#3619508). But despite his elaborate explanations, I found it really hard to understand.

---

Then, I tried it the hard way. It's only a 2-step solution. Nothing fancy.
$$ (y''')^{4/3}+y=-(y')^{1/5}$$
First, take power $5$ both sides,
$$ 5y^4(y''')^{4/3}+10y^{3}(y''')^{8/3}+5y(y''')^{16/3}+(y''')^{20/3}=-y'-y^5-10y^2(y''')^{4}$$

$$ (y''')^{4/3}[5y^4+5y(y''')^{4}]+(y''')^{8/3}[10y^{3}+(y''')^{4}]=-y'-y^5-10y^2(y''')^{4}$$
This is equivalent to $A+B=C$. $A$ is $O(\frac{16}{3})$. $B$ is $O(\frac{20}{3})$. $C$ is $O(4)$.

Cubing both sides $A^3+B^3 +3AB(A+B)=C^3$, where $A+B=C$ can be substituted from the above equation.
$$A^3+B^3 +3ABC=C^3$$
$$ (y''')^{4}[5y^4+5y(y''')^{4}]^{3}+(y''')^{8}[10y^{3}+(y''')^{4}]^{3}+3(y''')^{4}[5y^4+5y(y''')^{4}][10y^{3}+(y''')^{4}][-y'-y^5-10y^2(y''')^{4}]=[-y'-y^5-10y^2(y''')^{4}]^{3}$$
$$ O(16)+O(20)+O(16)=O(12)$$

So, the degree comes out to be $20$. Evidently, the bookish answer of $60$ must be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you raise both sides to the $15$th power, the equation is polynomial in $y,\, y'$ and $y''',$ with the latter clearly being of degree $20.$