# Find the degree of the differential equation $\left( \frac{d^3y}{dx^3} \right)^{\frac{4}{3}} + \left( \frac{dy}{dx} \right)^{\frac{1}{5}} + y = 0.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\left( \frac{d^3y}{dx^3} \right)^{\frac{4}{3}} + \left(
 \frac{dy}{dx} \right)^{\frac{1}{5}} + y = 0.$$

To convert it to a polynomial equation i have separated the differential terms and raised the power to 3 both sides,but could solve it further.
(The answer is 60)

Comment: you'll need to raise it to the power of 15 if you want to eliminate both fractional powers.

Comment: It is usually not well regarded to [repost the same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3617822/115115) if it was closed for quality reasons without trying to improve the quality of the existing question to get it re-opened. For instance, what is the definition of "degree"? And if you modify the equation, how does the degree for the new equation relate to this one? Does it matter if the solution set is not the same?

Comment: Note that the answer is changed, 60 is not the correct solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ODE does not have a polynomial structure, thus no degree.
The degree tells us how many different solution curves can go through a given state, counting multiplicities and over the complex field. In that sense one can directly solve for the highest derivative,
$$
y'''=\sqrt[4]{-\left(\sqrt[5]{y'}+y\right)^3}.
$$
There are 5 branches for the fifth root and for each of them 4 branches for the 4th root, giving $20$ variants for $y'''$.

One could also ask what the degree of $a$ is in the minimal polynomial in $\Bbb Q[a,b,c][x]$ that has a factor
$$
a^{\frac43}+b^{\frac15}+c.
$$
This is a resultant computation problem. Over some suitable extension and up to a sign, the resultant can be expressed as product over the roots,
$$
Res_\alpha(Res_\beta(a\alpha+\beta+c,\beta^5-b),\alpha^3-a)
=\prod_{α:α^3=a}\prod_{β:β^5=b}(a\alpha+\beta+c)
$$
The leading term in $a$ and $α$ is
$$
(aα_1aα_2aα_3)^5=a^{15}(α_1α_2α_3)^5=a^{20}
$$
using the Vieta rule that the constant coefficient is the product of the negative roots, or $α_1α_2α_3=a$.

Without further detail it is not possible to say where the answer $60$ comes from, it looks as if someone just took the product of all numbers in the exponents without regard to their place there.

Comment: The solution is incomplete.

Comment: @gemspark : Changed it to reflect the comments to the other question. It was not incomplete but wrong, division by 3 is not multiplication by 3.